# Runtime undefined errors from my shared library

Tags: hyperlink, malloc, undefined, customization, symbols

I face one issue in my customized `malloc()`.

## My software

First of all, let me explain my software:
My software is huge and is composed of multiple static libraries. As one of static libraries has the customized `malloc()`, whose main function is a sort of proprietary memory tracer on the top of calling `mall()` from glibc. Currently the customized `malloc()` is available only some applications but not all applications in my system. My aim is to link the customized `malloc()` to every application running on my system. In my previous post, I asked why there was 'undefined sysmbol' shown during the run time even though I used the flag of LTLD_LAZY. It turned out the my code was not correct. So I fixed my code. And the issue is resolved. But still I have an issue. Let me explain my code first.

1. cat common.c

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void *gp_malloc(size_t size) {
       void *ptr;
       ptr = malloc(size);
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: size(%d) = %p\n", __func__, (int)size, ptr);
       return ptr;
   }

   void gp_free(void *ptr) {
       free(ptr);
       fprintf(stderr, "%s free=%p\n", __func__, ptr);
   }
   ```
2. cat my_malloc.c

   ```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <dlfcn.h>
   #include <malloc.h>

   static void *handle = NULL;
   static void *(*gp_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;
   static void (*gp_free)(void *ptr) = NULL;

   void *my_malloc(size_t size) {
       char *error;
       void *ptr;

       /* dynamically load the shared lib that contains gp_malloc() */
       if (gp_malloc == NULL) {
           handle = dlopen("./libcommon.so", RTLD_LAZY| RTLD_GLOBAL);
           if (!handle) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
               return NULL;
           }
           /* get a pointer to the gp_malloc() function we just loaded */
           gp_malloc = dlsym(handle, "gp_malloc");
           if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
               return NULL;
           }
       }

       /* Now we can call gp_malloc() just like any other function */
       fprintf(stderr, "%s size=%ld\n", __func__, size);
       ptr = gp_malloc(size);
       return ptr;
   }

   void my_free(void *ptr) {
       char *error;
       //void *ptr;

       /* dynamically load the shared lib that contains gp_malloc() */
       if (gp_free == NULL) {
           gp_free = dlsym(handle, "gp_malloc");
           if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
               return;
           }
       }

       /* Now we can call gp_malloc() just like any other function */
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: start %p\n", __func__, ptr);
       gp_free(ptr);
   }

   void bbb(void) {
       extern void aaa(void);
       aaa();
   }
   ```
3. cat hello_exits.c

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   extern void *gp_malloc(int);
   extern void gp_free(void *);

   int main(void) {
       char *ptr;
       ptr = gp_malloc(10);
       gp_free(ptr);
       exit(0);
   }
   ```
4. cat hello_new.c

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include "my_malloc.h"

   int main(void) {
       char *ptr;
       ptr = malloc(10);
       free(ptr);
   }
   ```
5. cat my_static.c

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   void aaa(void) {
       printf("I am in aaa\n");
   }
   ```
6. cat my_malloc.h

   ```
   #ifdef COMPILE_TIME_MY_MALLOC
   #define malloc(size) my_malloc(size)
   #define free(ptr) my_free(ptr)
   void *my_malloc(size_t size);
   void my_free(void *ptr);
   #endif
   ```
7. cat Makefile_new

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH=${shell pwd}
   all:
           gcc -c -Wall -fPIC -o my_malloc.o -c my_malloc.c
           gcc -O2 -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libmy_malloc.so my_malloc.o
   #       This shared library is built with Makefile_exist
   #       gcc -O2 -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libcommon.so common.c
           gcc -L${LOCAL_PATH} -g -Wall -D COMPILE_TIME_MY_MALLOC -o hello_new hello_new.c -lmy_malloc -ldl
   ```
8. cat Makefile_exist

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH=${shell pwd}
   all:
           gcc -c -Wall -o my_static.o -c my_static.c
           ar -rc libmy_static.a my_static.o

           gcc -O2 -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libcommon.so common.c
           gcc -L${LOCAL_PATH}  -g -Wall -o hello_exist hello_exist.c  -lcommon -lmy_static -ldl
   ```

In order to build the image, run Makefile_exist, Makefile_new sequentially so that hello_new is created. (Makefile_exist/Makefile_new is a simplified version of my makefiles. The former is one that I use. The later is one that I am going to apply to other applications)

When I run `hello_new`, I got `gp_malloc` twice. I understand the 1st one. What causes the 2nd `gp_malloc()`?

```
./hello_new
my_malloc size=10
gp_malloc: size(10) = 0x7fffe0d5b900
my_free: start 0x7fffe0d5b900
gp_malloc: size(-522864384) = (nil)         //what causes this to be called.
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Another idea would be not using any home-made malloc at all. Really. If you have memory-allocation-problems, use valgrind to find them.

Comment: Hey! Your question is very detailed - but can you start it with a simple statement of the problem (i.e. what are you trying to do and how is it failing), before you jump in to the details of your system?

Comment: You use the C preprocessor to replace all calls to `malloc()` with calls to `my_malloc()`, which calls `gp_malloc()`, which in turn calls the ambiant `malloc()` function. Do you have the same hooks for `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `strdup()`? Do you instrument `free()` as well? Does `gp_malloc()` return the pointer it gets from `malloc()` or do you store ancillary information in the block and return a modified pointer? Can you post the link errors you get?

Comment: Thank you everybody for your replies. I am asked to stick to existing home-made malloc. Also there was an issue in my code when I did test before my 1st post. After fixing it, I post all codes that I use. I will have the hooks for calloc(), realloc(). But I have not thought strdup(). Special thank you, ChQrlie about it.